# Docker cannot access published port from other container

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube

There are two container jenkins and sonarqube which are both under network ci.

I can access sonarqube from jenkins using linked hostname and exposed port, but cannot access using host ip and published port.

```sh
# docker exec jenkins nc -zv sonarqube 9000
sonarqube (172.19.0.5:9000) open

# docker exec jenkins nc -zv PHYSICAL_HOST_IP 9000
nc: PHYSICAL_HOST_IP (PHYSICAL_HOST_IP:9000): Host is unreachable
```

`PHYSICAL_HOST_IP` is the IP of docker host (or physical machine), e.g. 10.x.x.x.

Here are docker-compose configs:

**docker-compose.jenkins.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

    jenkins:
        image: jenkinsci/blueocean
        container_name: jenkins
        restart: always
        external_links:
            - sonarqube:sonarqube
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        privileged: true
        networks:
            - ci

networks:
  ci:
     external: true
```

**docker-compose.sonarqube.yml**

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:8.4.2-community
    container_name: sonarqube
    restart: always
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - ci
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=user
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=password
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonarqube

  db:
    image: postgres:12.4
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    networks:
      - ci
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=sonarqube

networks:
  ci:
     external: true
```

And network ci:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "ci",
        "Id": "...",
        "Created": "...",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            ...
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: in your case, what's PHYSICAL_HOST_IP ? this is : 172.19.0.5 ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan No, it's the IP of docker host (or physical machine), e.g. 10.x.x.x.

Comment: in the container, it doesnot know physical host ip,  so you cannot ping ro reach it, in your case, you created a custom  network its name : ci

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the host in the sonar.properties file under `http.nonProxyHost`

Follow this two post for more details:

1. https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/150
2. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/http-nonproxyhosts-has-no-effect-webhook-delivery-failing-ce-7-9-1-build-27448/17630

Hope this might resolve your issue.